# Swift command line linking fails with "duplicate symbols" error

Tags: swift, macos, swift4, swift4.1, perfect

I am referencing some C projects in my Package.swift. Recently I have added a project that references other C projects in its own Package.swift file, and while those C projects are different from my referenced projects, they contain same-name object files. Building on command line using `swift build` or `swift run` gives me a "duplicate symbol" error during linking.

e.g.

```
duplicate symbol _http_message_needs_eof in:
    /Users/tyress/private/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
    /Users/tyress/private/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/PerfectCHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_should_keep_alive in:
    /Users/tyress/private/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
    /Users/tyress/private/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/PerfectCHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_parser_execute in:
    /Users/tyress/private/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
    /Users/tyress/private/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/PerfectCHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_parser_pause in:
    /Users/tyress/private/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
    /Users/tyress/private/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/PerfectCHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
duplicate symbol _http_errno_name in:
    /Users/tyress/private/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/CHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
    /Users/tyress/private/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/PerfectCHTTPParser.build/http_parser.c.o
```

The build finally fails with `<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` (this message shows up even when built with -v)

Building it on Xcode 9.3 produces no such error and runs normally on debug.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this build from failing with duplicates? I would need to be able to build it through command-line.

Comment: Tried clean build?

Comment: @Bista yes, I'm on 4.1 though so I had to do `swift package clean` but I've also tried deleting all .build folder files, removing/regenerating xcodeproj, etc.